# Adjusting a texture's color temperature

Tags: hdri

I'm fairly new to Blender. I have a HDRI background and I wonder if it's possible to adjust the texture's color temperature using a blackbody node.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To adjust the color temperature I believe you must use some color adjustment node live *RGB Curves* or *Hue Saturation*. The *Black Body* node is used more commonly to simulate realistic lamp light color by converting temperature color into standard RGB

Comment: I think I've seen CG cookie has a node package including a color temperature node.

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying the color of the HDRi with the blackbody color seems to do what you want. I don't know if it's physically accurate however.

*Multiply* node is added by adding a *Color* > *MixRGB* node and changing the operator to *Multiply*

[image]

Comment: No, you cannot just multiply some warm or cold color over the image - because that will change the luminance of the image. RGB needs to be converted into HSL, do the temperature adjustment on H and S channels and the L channel needs to remain unchanged. Then converted back to RGB. It is though much better to directly change the whitepoint of image by converting into XYZ space then into LAB, where the reference white point can be easily changed.

Comment: You can check the luminance by this formula L=0.5*(max(R,G,B)+min(R,G,B))

Comment: hmm, debating whether to delete the answer or not. It still gives the reader somewhere to start...

Comment: just for the record, this helps, but its not what i needed. 

a hue node worked for me but not to my exact needs.